# Network disconnects precisely at same time

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have network disconnections with my laptop and they occur only when I work at home. The wired and/or wireless network disconnects at the same time approximately : 10:10 AM then 10:20 AM.

To get back the network, I have to manually disconnect it, then re-connect via the top-right menu.

This problem isn't caused by my internet provider at home because I never have network disconnections on my personal laptop or on my smartphone.

Also, I don't face the disconnections when I use my work laptop in our office.

I have a DELL Latitude E6540 (2015 edition) with Ubuntu 15.04.

Do you same clues to help find the cause of this timed disconnections ?

Is it possible I have a script that re-starts the network at same time on some conditions ?

Thx!

Comment: 15.04 is EOL, and questions about it are off-topic here.  Upgrade to the latest version of Ubuntu, then [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/747404/edit)  your question if you still have the problem.

Comment: Also, try updating the firmware on your router.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your router's parental control menu , someone has just put your mac id to be disconnected at that time....or you may have done it accidentaly

Comment: I haven't set this action on the router settings. Actually, I can't do this type of timed action on my router.

Comment: @Dino Jot down your username and password from the router's menu and  reset your router to the factory settings.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the DHCP lease time? Does the router release the address after 24 hours, perhaps? (Of course, you would then want to ask why it didn't refresh automatically)